# Values echoing outside of specified area

Tags: php, html

We have a function like this:

```
function getthis($x){
    $dbc = getDBCon();

    if ($dbc) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            SOME PROCESS...
            echo $results; 
        }

        closeDBCon($dbc)
    }
```

and in page:

```
<?php

$get = getthis($x)
echo '<td>'.$get.'</td>';

?>
```

But it doesn't `echo` results inside `<tr>` tags and they appear on top of page. It is probably `echo`ing instead of `return`, but what is causing this problem?

Comment: "probably echoing instead of "return" causes this problem?" Yes.

Comment: but return breakes out function and only returns one value.. , and why it doesnt echo into tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say yourself, `echo` instead of `return` is the problem. `echo` just prints to the screen exactly when the method is encountered. A possible solution can be to accumlate your results in a variable `$output` throughout the while loop. Once you're done, you return the contents of `$output`.

```
function getthis($x){
    $dbc = getDBCon();
    $output = "";
    if($dbc) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            // SOME PROCESS...
            $output .= $results;
        }
        closeDBCon($dbc);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: closeDBCon($dbc) needs the `;`

Answer (score 1):

When you run the function, the page processes the echo request in the function before the one on the page, and so echos it, while returning no value.

As you obviously want to close the DB connection, a good alternative would be to store the result as a variable during the loop, then return the variable after closing the connection. This way when you echo $get, it's echoing the function return.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the problem. You can either `echo` in the right order:

```
<?php
echo '<td>';
getthis($x);
echo '</td>';
?>
```

Convert to `return`:

```
function getthis($x) {
    $output = '';
    $dbc = getDBCon();

    if($dbc) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            SOME PROCESS...

            $output .= $results;
        }

        closeDBCon($dbc);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Or perform output buffering:

```
<?php

ob_start();
getthis($x);
$get = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo '<td>'.$get.'</td>';

?>
```

Comment: I think it's great you present him with multiple solutions, but some solutions are better than others. You might want to emphasize which is preferable.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: It depends on whether or not `getthis()` can be changed, but I did list them in order of preference.

Comment: when quitting `while` loop, it dosnt know `$output` anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't agree, though. Having arbitrary methods printing to the screen is anarchy and bad practice. It makes it impossible for you to later decide to send a new header.

Comment: @W2-S `$output` is declared outside of the `while` loop, so it will still be in scope when doing `return $output`.

Comment: @W2-S and Kristian Antonsen: Actually, it's not declared anywhere. PHP doesn't have such a concept. There's function scope and there's global scope.

Comment: ok, it works finally with ur and Kristian Antonsen's help. tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to `return` the data, rather than `echo`ing it. Right now you're calling the function `getthis()`, and it is internally printing the data out. Instead, you want it to return the values so you can control where the results get printed:

```
function getthis( $x ) {
    $dbc = getDBCon();
    $response = false; /* Return false if no db connection was made */
    if( $dbc ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
        $res = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sql );
        $response = "";
        while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array( $res ) ){ 
            /* SOME PROCESS... */
            $response .= $results; /* Assuming you're returning a string */
        }
    closeDBCon($dbc);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

On a side-note, I wouldn't be opening and closing connections within a function like this. You could be adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: as i say to minitech, when quitting `while` loop, it dosnt know `$response` or `$results` anymore.

Comment: @W2-S You should share your updated code - `$response` is within appropriate scope, and the function *can* return it if you've followed the example above.

Answer (score 0):

echo the td tags within the function or else return the $results